# Required from one URL to another including the query strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mybb

I just can't figure out the way to redirect all the URLs from *http://moneycodeking.com* to *http://seosatanforum.com*.

I found a piece of code with Google and it does work but redirects just the homepage, but not when URL contains query, for example:

*moneycodeking.com* WILL load *seosatanforum.com*.

but *www.moneycodeking.com/**showthread.php?tid=244*** won't load
*www.seosatanforum.com/**showthread.php?tid=244***

Any help is highly appreciated.

My .htaccess had:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.seosatanforum.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]
```

But it returned loop error said redirection kept repeating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both Domains are on  the same server, you can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```